# Meaning of "{Someone's} got jokes ..."

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, slang

The following appears as an example sentence in this entry on [UrbanDictionary.com](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Got+Jokes&defid=1636027):

> Timmy's got jokes if he thinks I'm going to sell him my $3000 rims for $500 bucks!

I need additional help in understanding what's mean by *got jokes* in this context.

Comment: Where did you hear this or see this?

Comment: This reminds me of the phrase 'you've got to be joking', which means you don't believe the person speaking to you is being serious, but phrased in this way it doesn't sound right, nor does it really make sense.

Comment: I saw this phrase somewhere in the internet, google show this [result](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Got+Jokes&defid=1636027). Do you think that _Timmy's_ is a short way for saying _Timmy has_

Comment: What @DaaaahWhoosh said. The speaker/writer is obviously *not* a native Anglophone. He's just "mangling" the standard colloquial usage *Timmy **must be joking** if he thinks [blah blah]*. Regardless of that though, the contracted *Timmy's* can only stand for *Timmy **has*** in OP's example, but it would have to stand for ***is*** if I reduced my version to *Timmy's joking if he...*

Comment: Maybe it's some sort of **extension** of **he's got game**?

Comment: @Hp93 Yes, in this sentence *Timmy's* is a contracted form of *Timmy has*.

Comment: Maybe it's a regionalism or something, but it looks like the phrase is listed in the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com%2Fdefine.php%3Fterm%3DGot%2BJokes%26).

Comment: I don't get you.  He doesn't  get a joke.  Get is used to mean understand (0xford Learner's)

Comment: Pretty much the only place I have ever seen this is on UrbanDictionary.com.  It does not seem to be a common usage.

Comment: I've located the likely source and edited the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As the comments suggested, *he's got jokes* is not a common idiomatic expression. It's clear from context what is meant ("he's got to be joking" or "he's kidding himself") but the phrase itself doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hi, so the phrase doesn't correct right? If the other part has been removed, does it still mean "he's got to be joking"? For example, someone just say "Timmy's got jokes.". How do you understand that? Timmy's got to be joking or Timmy made a joke? Sorry I'm not a native speaker and just wonder if this is somehow grammatically correct.

Comment: It is grammatically correct, it just doesn't make much sense in the original sentence you posted. The phrase *Timmy's got jokes*, by itself, literally means "Timmy owns or is in possession of jokes". The original sentence was using this phrase non-literally like an idiom, but it's not an idiom. It would be fine to use the phrase in a literal context: "Do you need an opening joke for your speech tonight? Timmy's got jokes. Maybe you can get some suggestions from him."

Comment: Also note that *To get a joke* is an idiomatic expression meaning "To understand a joke". You might be able to use this phrase in that context as well.

Comment: @Era I think your answer meeds to be reconsidered now that the question has been edited. The entire example sentence appears in the Urban Dictionary, with a different meaning. If it actially has such a meaning for more than the writer of the entry is another questionn

Comment: @JimReynolds No, the meaning is the same as what I said (phrased slightly differently). There are numerous expressions that mean the same thing, like "You can't be serious." Additionally, Urban Dictionary is not a "real" dictionary and **should not** be used as a unilateral source for inexperienced learners of English. It has a *huge* number of entries that are total nonsense or only used within very specific speech communities.